# Athena AWS python client get query size

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Is there any way to get the query size using the `query_execution_id` without downloading the csv file?. Using the [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html) client.

Comment: [`get_query_runtime_statistics`}(https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_runtime_statistics) and input/output bytes returned by it? Or [`get_query_execution`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_execution)?